# Add m2m relation in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to add multiple m2m relationship between two objects in Django rest framework

```
  class Theme(models.Model):
        slug = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, db_index=True)
        menu = models.ManyToManyField(Menu, related_name='themes')


class Menu(models.Model):
    pass
```

Serializer

```
class MenuAdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    themes = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True,
                                          read_only=False,
                                          required=False,
                                          slug_field='slug',
                                          queryset=Theme.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('themes',)


    def create(self, validated_data):
        themes = validated_data.pop('themes')
        menu.themes.set(*themes)
```

I pass themes like this ["one", "another"] but the error im getting is `'Theme' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your adding many to many field is not appropriate.

```
 menu.themes.set(*themes)
```

This should change to

```
 menu.themes_set.add(*themes)
```

Relevant [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)